# How to call Grails from Scala

Tags: scala, grails

Is there a way to call a method in a Grails service, from a Scala class that is running on the same JVM?
I have seen something similar done from Groovy/Griffon but cannot figure out how to accomplish that in Grails. (http://www.jroller.com/aalmiray/entry/griffon_groovy_scala_working_together)

Basically, one of my Grails controllers calls some Scala code, which should return some values asynchronously. So, I guess, the only way to return those values is by calling back a method in a Grails service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way of doing it, inspired by the link in the question above, and one of the FAQs in the Grails website.

On the Scala side:
Declare an object similar to the following:

```
package scalaCallback

object ScalaCallback{
    var cback: {def callback(example: String)} = null

    def setCallback(cb: {def callback(example: String)}){
        cback = cb
    }

    def invokeCallback(example: String){
        if(callback != null) cback.callback(example)
    }
}
```

On the Grails side:

Create a class in src/groovy similar to the following:

```
package groovyCallback
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder

class GroovyCallback{
    private GroovyCallback() {}
    private static final INSTANCE = new GroovyCallback()

    static getInstance(){ return INSTANCE }

    void callback(String example){
        ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.yourService.yourMethod(example)   
    }
}
```

In your BootStrap.groovy init add the following:

```
scalaCallback.cback = groovyCallback.GroovyCallback.getInstance()
```

When you call invokeCallback("example") in Scala, it will call yourService.yourMethod("example")

Note: the jar file with your Scala class should be in the lib folder of you Grails application

Answer (score 1):

Your Grails service is a Spring bean.   @Autowire the service into your Scala class (it will need to be a bean/@Component) and call the method.

**EDIT** - added example:

For example (using Java, not Scala but the approach is exactly the same):

Java code calling service:

```
package grailstest;

@Component
public class ServiceInjectionTester {
    @Autowired TestService testService;

    public String testTheService() {
        return testService.serviceMethod();
    }
}
```

Service:

```
class TestService {
    String serviceMethod() {
        return "success"
    }
}
```

In Config.groovy:

```
grails.spring.bean.packages = [ "grailstest" ]
```

You can also wire your Java/Scala bean into your Grails classes:

```
class TestController {
    @Autowired
    ServiceInjectionTester serviceInjectionTester

    def index = { 
        render(text: serviceInjectionTester.testTheService())
    }
}
```

References:

[Grails Reference 8.4 - Using Services from Java](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/8.%20The%20Service%20Layer.html)

[Spring: The Foundation for Grails](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/06/08/spring-the-foundation-for-grails/)

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how you would do that? Do you also need any XML config for Spring?

Comment: Added example.  No XML is needed.